# Sending image through pipe to child process in C

Tags: c, pipe, fork, display

What my program needs to do is create child process, then transform it into dipslay program and send a PNG image through a pipe to it. I think i'm close, but i don't know how to send an image through pipe.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    int     fd[2];
    pid_t   childpid;

    char    string[] = "";
    char    readbuffer[10000];
char    buf[10000];
FILE *fptr;

    pipe(fd);

    if((childpid = fork()) == -1)
    {
            perror("fork");
            exit(1);
    }

    if(childpid == 0)
    {
            //Child
            close(fd[1]);
    dup(fd[0]);
    execl("/usr/bin/display","display", (char *)0);
    read(fd[0], readbuffer, sizeof(readbuffer));
            exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
    //Parent
    close(fd[0]);
    dup2(fd[1],1);
    printf("Type name of the file:\n");
    scanf("%s",string);
    fptr = fopen(string, "r");
     while ( fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), fptr) != NULL) {
            write(fd[1], buf, strlen(buf));
            }

    fclose(fptr);

    }

    return(0);
```

Comment: You must use `read`, not `fgets`. Image files, in general, do not have "strings."

Comment: Did you mean something like this? 
It does not work.while ( read(fptr, buf, strlen(buf)) != EOF) {
        write(fd[1], buf, strlen(buf));
                }

Comment: So i figured out something like this:
while ( c != EOF) {
  
   read(fptr,&c,1);
   buf[i]=c;
   if(strcmp(&c,"\n") || strcmp(&c,"\0")) i=0;
          write(fd[1], buf, strlen(buf));
                }
Yet it doesnt work still. Where am i making mistake?

Comment: Another problem that i noticed is that, when i run the program it just launches ImageMagick (display command) instead of waiting for name input.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to close the file descriptor associated with standard input.

```
close(0);
```

then duplicate fd[0]. It should work. You don't need to duplicate fd[1] in parent process.

My program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>


int main()
{
  int pipe_fd[2];
  int c;
  FILE *file;


  pipe(pipe_fd);

  if(fork()==0)
    {
      //child
      close(pipe_fd[1]);
      close(0);
      dup(pipe_fd[0]);
      execl("/usr/bin/display","display", (char*)NULL);
      read(pipe_fd[0], &c, 1);
      exit(1);
    }
      // parent
      close(pipe_fd[0]);
      file=fopen("Lena2.pgm","r");
      if(file==NULL)
        printf("File error\n");
      while(!feof(file))
        {
          c=getc(file);
          write(pipe_fd[1], &c, 1);
        }
}
```